# Symfony 2: Force https for all routes

Tags: php, http, symfony

I have made a web application in the symfony 2 framework. 
This is working fine but now i want to change the http:// to https:// for all the routes!

And how can I check if my environment is localhost in this. If I work locally I want to use the normal http://.

Where to set this, i can't find it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can check this tutorial/code for make a good and simple redirection : https://roadtodev.com/configurer-htaccess-symfony-avec-https-et-sans-www

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you go:
(Not tested but should work.)

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https, host: yourdomain\.com$ }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http, host: localhost$ }
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html#forcing-a-channel-http-https

Comment: Thanks this is working but how can i check if my environment is localhost in this. 

If i work locally i want to use the normal http:// headers.

Thanks!

Comment: updated my answer (and your question) and for further questions, please read the docs first. ;)

Comment: @Markus, Is it possible to force use of `www` ? If it's not possible from `access_control`. Can we do it from `.htacess`?